# Selenium click sometimes causes page to load and sometimes doesn't

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Clicking on a button in my web page sometimes causes the entire page to load, and sometimes only part of it to load. 
How can I call waitForPageToLoad without the page loading, and to be able to run additional commands after all elements are present, or what other command can I use, that will wait for the page to be loaded and enable me to run additional commands on the page.
(Using selenium 2.)

Answer (score 2):

> Clicking on a button in my web page sometimes causes the entire page to load, and sometimes only part of it to load.

I assume this is by design, and not the problem.

If you are testing, then you should know which behavior you are expecting.  If you are expecting a full page load, then use `clickAndWait`.  If you are expecting a partial load, then use `click` followed by `waitForCondition`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wait()` command to wait a specified amount of time, and continue with your actions afterward.

```
synchronized (driver) {
        try {
            driver.wait(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It may be better to use `clickAndWait` or `waitForCondition`, but this is an alternative for just waiting in general.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for element you want to proceed with instead of wait for page to load